# Remote xterm terminating with an error event BadAccess

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, xterm, x-windows, bell

I'm logging into a remote server using `ssh -x` and then running `xterm`.  Whenever the keyboard bell is trying to be run, I get the following messages and xterm exits:

```
xterm: warning, error event received:
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  104 (X_Bell)
  Serial number of failed request:  468
  Current serial number in output stream:  469
```

This was all working perfectly fine when I went home last night and was failing when I came back in this morning.  As far as I can tell, nothing has changed.

I've tried turning off the bell (`xset b off`) locally and remotely.  Remotely, I get a similar error, but for `X_ChangeKeyboardControl`.  Locally, the `xterm` still exits with the same error.

I looked on my system and do not have a `xconf.d` directory.

`uname -a` returns the following:

```
Linux <node-name> 4.18.0-16-generic #17~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12 13:35:51 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I have the same issue while accessing a remote xterm between FreeBSD 12 boxes.

Answer (score 1):

(Bradford's answer is correct, but to expand on what he wrote)

That's the result of the limitations placed on X11 Forwarding by the default ssh client config. If you have access, add both `ForwardX11 yes` and `ForwardX11Trusted yes` to the system `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` which will enable the desired behavior by default for all users on the system.

Otherwise, invoke `ssh -Y` when connecting to relevant hosts.

Here is how the ssh_config(5) man page describes the `ForwardX11` setting:

> **ForwardX11** Specifies whether X11 connections will be automatically redirected over the secure channel and DISPLAY set. The argument must
> be ''yes'' or ''no''. The default is ''no''.
>
> X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution. Users with the ability
> to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the user's X11
> authorization database) can access the local X11 display through the
> forwarded connection. An attacker may then be able to perform
> activities such as keystroke monitoring if the ForwardX11Trusted
> option is also enabled.

Here is how the ssh_config(5) man page describes the `ForwardX11Trusted` setting:

> **ForwardX11Trusted** If this option is set to ''yes'', remote X11 clients
> will have full access to the original X11 display.
>
> If this option is set to ''no'', remote X11 clients will be considered
> untrusted and prevented from stealing or tampering with data belonging
> to trusted X11 clients. Furthermore, the xauth(1) token used for the
> session will be set to expire after 20 minutes. Remote clients will be
> refused access after this time.
>
> The default is ''no''.
>
> See the X11 SECURITY extension specification for full details on the
> restrictions imposed on untrusted clients.

I verified the issue and fix on my FreeBSD 13.1 system (client) connecting to a Redhat Linux server (server).

Note sshd_config enables `X11Forwarding` by default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.

I believe the fix is that you need to also enable "trusted" X11 forwarding by either using the `-Y` option instead of `-X` or by using `ForwardX11Trusted yes` in your `.ssh/config` file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).